# How to insert a row of data in my MySQL table from command line?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm using MySQL command line and need to insert data into my table. I'm having a major brain fart and feel really rusty on this and cannot remember on how to do this correctly. Here is how my table looks currently:

[image]

I deleted items from my database, and this is all that is left in my books table. I want to add another book that has the title "Faith" and the author "Nelson", so I tried the following command, but get an error as you can see below:

[image]

I don't want to enter information for the key, I want it to generate automatically without me having to manually enter it. Can someone please show me how to enter this data correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO books (`title`, `author`)
VALUES
    ('faith', 'nelson');
```

Comment: Do you know how I can edit my books table so that the key can auto_increment?

Comment: If `booksKey` be an auto increment column, then MySQL should automatically increment it.

Comment: The table doesn't auto_increment, I need to modify it but cant figure out how.

Comment: I figured it out, this is how you add auto increment to my existing table above:

**alter table books modify booksKey int auto_increment;**